# Ionic how to set Sass variables of a platform like another

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I want to set some Sass variables of a platform (for example, those related to the toolbar) and make them have the same values as another platform.

I can do that by changing the value of each variable, but is there a quicker way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of platform specific css this can be accomplished, for example to target the bar-header class on the android platform

```
.platform-android .bar-header {
 text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

Example of other options, to target specific operating systems

- **iOS 8**    *.platform-ios8*    The OS on the device is running iOS 8
- **iOS 8.4**  *platform-ios8_4*   The OS on the device is running iOS 8.4. This
  class is applied in addition to platform-ios8
- **Android 4**    *.platform-android4*    The OS on the device is running Android 4
- **Android 4.4**  *.platform-android4_4*  The OS on the device is running
  Android 4.4. This class is applied, in addition to platform-android4